# c# Shutdown a system after holding yes for 5 seconds

Tags: c#, dialog, shutdown

I was wondering if anyone knows how to use a dialog box to create a hold down button event. Here is the scenerio:

a user would like to shutdown their system, but because it is critical that they confirm, that user must hold the button for 5 seconds before the action can be done.

I am trying to do it in a yes no scenario ie.

To confirm shutdown please hold "Yes" for 5 seconds.

Anyone done this before able to offer a little help/insight?

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. First, because you should not interrupt a system shutdown, as it could occur because of a remote shutdown request and there is simple no operator to answer Yes. And second, because the idea of 5 second hold is just wrong. How would an user hold Yes if he only has a Keyboard? At worse, ask the user to type in `Yes` in a text box.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu - I think he is trying to initiate the shutdown, not abort/interupt it, and I don't know that it is such a bad idea....this how many people turn off their mobile devices.

Comment: To initiate a system shutdown I agree is a OK, but such an app layer mechanism would be basically useless as there are plenty of OS ways for a user to initiate a shutdown that would bypass this confirmation (Start/Shutdown, run shutdown.exe, Setup/msi reboot, someone calling Win32Shutdown on WMI, applications calling `InitiateShutdown` etc etc).

Answer (score 5):

Try using a button's Mouse_Down & Mouse_Up event, and a timer (this assumes you're using WinForms).

```
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.timer1.Enabled == false)
        {
            this.timer1.Interval = 5000;
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Shutdown!");
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: Good, but couldn't you just set the interval to 5 seconds; and shutdown when the timer ticks once?

Comment: @ Gendolkari - yes, you could :) - been a while since doing WinForms. Edited.

Comment: Also, you aren't checking to see if the user is actually clicking the button. This will shut down after 5 seconds no matter where the user clicks.

Comment: @Gendolkari -- Obviously the event would be tied to it's handler, which in this case looks like it would be a button.

Comment: Eww. Bad side effect. To clarify Gendolkari's statement. If you click and hold the button, and move off the button while still holding the mouse button down... the event will still be fired. May need to do a bit more creative coding.

Comment: Sorry, I was mixed up and thinking that you had to do MouseDown on the form, instead of on the button itself (seems I'm not alone in this thinking, as others have suggested checking where the mouse is). But if the button itself has a MouseDown event, then of course my thinking was wrong.

Comment: @JTA - ah ok, so I'm not completely crazy. :)

Answer (score 4):

You could capture the button press on 'mousedown', and start a 5-second timer. Once the timer completes, shutdown is initiated. If a 'mouseup' event happens, it could stop and reset the timer.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, handle BOTH the mousedown event and the mouseup event. Start a timer on the mousedown and see how long it has run on the mouseup. Done!

Comment: What if the user holds the button down longer? Should it just wait until they release to determine whether to trigger the shutdown, or do it as soon as 5 seconds has passed before the mouseup triggers?

Comment: That depends on how you want to handle the shutdown process. If the purpose is to wait for the user to release the button and then measure the elapsed time, just do it like I described above. If you want to wait for the user to hold down the button for exactly five seconds, then shutdown the system, start a Timer and handle the shutdown in the timer Tick event. A premature mouseup could then stop and reset the timer again. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this any number of ways.  The first that comes to my mind would be to spin off a thread that waits 5 seconds and is simply aborted if the user's mouse comes back up.

```
    Thread shutdown;
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        shutdown = new Thread(()=>ShutDown());
        shutdown.Start();
    }

    private void ShutDown()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.Write("5 seconds has elapsed");
        // Do something.
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (shutdown != null)
        {
            shutdown.Abort();
            shutdown = null;
        }
    }
```

Low overhead and you're not adding additional supporting controls for something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother when you can just use getAsyncKeyState()? Tell them to hold down 'y' for 5 seconds. You can find a reference here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate

Or you can do it your way and start a timer on MouseDown, then on MouseUp, end the timer and then see if it's more or less than 5 seconds. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Form.MouseDown events do detect that the user has pressed the mouse button. In the event handler, check to see if cursor is over the button or not (the event is passed in the coordinates of the cursor). You can then enable a timer which will tick in 5 seconds, and perform the shutdown when the timer ticks.

Answer (score 0):

When the user first clicks YES, start a timer that repeatedly checks if the mouse location is inside of the button. After 5 seconds has elapsed, proceed with the shutdown. If the user moves the mouse out of the button, stop the timer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private DateTime mouseDownTime;

private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDownTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void Button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (mouseDownTime.AddSeconds(5) < DateTime.Now)
        MessageBox.Show("You held it for 5 seconds!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a timer on the MouseDown event, and if the mouse capture changes (check the MouseCaptureChanged event) to false before the timer event fires, cancel the timer.